# how to skip the first 2 lines of csv file?

Tags: elixir

The csv file contains two line which are extra version explanation and duplicate header. I want to skip the first two lines.

how to modify here?

```
# path = "/Users/yuchen/Downloads/test.csv"
product_data =
  path
  |> File.stream!()
  |> CSV.decode!(separator: ?;, headers: true)
  |> Enum.take(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Stream.drop/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#drop/2) is your friend. Also you’d likely need not raising [`CSV.decode/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html#decode/2) version.

```elixir
product_data =
  path
  |> File.stream!()
  |> CSV.decode(separator: ?;, headers: true)
  |> Stream.drop(2)
  |> ...
```

---

*Sidenote:* I’d suggest using [`NimbleCSV`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv/NimbleCSV.html#c:parse_stream/2), skipping headers and dropping two lines as shown below.

```elixir
path
|> File.stream!(read_ahead: 100_000)
|> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream()
|> Stream.drop(2)
|> …
```